# How do I find a specific string in the Description field on Computer Objects in AD?

Tags: powershell, automation, active-directory

Currently the description field for computer objects is in use in Active Directory with Name of user,type of computer and date put in service. I have a powershell script to identify computer objects that are both 30 days and 44 days old that appends the label "More than 30 Days Old" and "More than 44 Days Old" to the description. Everytime I run the script I want to check to see if that label has already been appended to the objects whom meet the 30 and 44 day inactive criteria. How do I search the Description properties for the labels I have already appended to them...so the inactive labels I set don't apply every time the script runs?

Currently this is how I am appending the inactive label for Inactive over 30 Days:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $time} -Properties Description | ForEach-Object {Set-ADComputer $_ -Description "$($_.Description) More than 30 Days Old" }
```

I would love to be able to check to see if the label already exists before attempting to append again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get the computers that do not have the appended labels:

```
$descriptionFilter = "*More than*days old*"
Get-ADComputer -Filter {LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $time -and description -notlike $descriptionFilter} -Properties Description | ForEach-Object {Set-ADComputer $_ -Description "$($_.Description) More than 30 Days Old" }
```

If you want to check beforehand and not make any changes, then just run:

```
$descriptionFilter = "*More than*days old*"
Get-ADComputer -Filter {LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $time -and description -notlike $descriptionFilter} -Properties Description
```

The middle asterisk of the descriptionFilter string can be substituted for  `30`  or  `44` , but be sure to include the spaces around the numbers. If you actually want to see the computers with the appended labels already, then just change out `-notlike` to `-like`.

Comment: You sir, just saved me a Gaussian proportion of time. Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! AdminofThings.